# В билд реакта не попали все фотографии

Tags: javascript, reactjs, изображения, build

У меня есть проект, в котором есть множество фотографий. Все фото лежат в папке `public/images`. Большинство фотографий отображаются нормально, но некоторые даже не попадают в билд проекта. Ниже пример части компонента в котором есть проблема

```
 <div className={styles.containerImage}>
   <img className={styles.image} src="/images/LotImage.png" alt="person" />
 </div>
 <div className={styles.containerImage}>
   <img
      className={styles.image}
      src="/images/PersonBack.png"
      alt="person"
    />
 </div>
```

Первая фотография не отображается, а вторая работает, хотя когда запускаешь localhost, всё работает ок. Почему такое может происходить?

Проект я размещал на vercel

Comment: Это довольно странно, так как при сборке если вы например используете *create-react-app* в качестве основы вашего проекта, все содержимое папки `/public`, должно просто переместится в готовую сборку без какой-либо обработки. Не могли бы вы добавить ссылку на собранный проект/часть проекта с ошибкой?

Comment: https://nft-react-voice60.vercel.app/ -  ссылка на готовый проект, https://github.com/Voice60/nft - ссылка на исходник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ответ

Ссылаясь на файлы, вы забываете указывать их в корректном регистре. Итак как **вся часть URL строки, кроме домена является чувствительной к регистру** вы просто ссылаетесь на файлы которые не существуют.

#### Пример

Вот один из примеров из вашего кода.

У вас есть следующая строка:

```
<img class="Story_ship__tsZlk" src="images/ship.png" alt="ship">
```

А в папке `public/images/` есть только такой файл `SHIP.png`.